# How to use Parameters type on overloaded functions?

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript, there is a built-in **Parameters** type that returns the parameters of a given function. It returns the parameters in a tuple.

Here's an example:

```
declare function foo(a: string, b: number): void;

type fooParams = Parameters<typeof foo>;
type aType = fooParams[0]; // string
type bType = fooParams[1]; // number
```

But, if we declare an overloaded function then I don't know how to get the **Parameters** of a specific arity for the overloaded function. Here's an example:

```
declare function foo(a: string, b: number): void;
declare function foo(a: boolean, b: string, c: string): void;

type fooParams = Parameters<typeof foo>;

type aType = fooParams[0]; // boolean
type bType = fooParams[1]; // string
```

It looks like whatever overloaded declaration for the function is last will be used in the **Parameters** type. To prove it, we can just reorder the function declarations:

```
declare function foo(a: boolean, b: string, c: string): void;
declare function foo(a: string, b: number): void;

type fooParams = Parameters<typeof foo>;

type aType = fooParams[0]; // string
type bType = fooParams[1]; // number
```

So the question is, how could I pull out the parameters for a specific overloaded function that I want (e.g. the **foo** function with an arity of 2)?

I ask because I tend to use the **Parameters** type when working with 3rd party libraries. So if a function is overloaded, then this can cause some issues when trying to use the correct parameter type for the correct overloaded function. An example of overloaded functions is the jQuery library with the **.on()** function.

Comment: You might have to work at it; the `Parameters` utility type is a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types), the documentation for which says "When inferring from a type with multiple call signatures (such as the type of an overloaded function), inferences are made from the *last* signature. ... It is not possible to perform overload resolution based on a list of argument types."  I've done something before to try to pull out particular overload signatures, but they're fragile.

Comment: "they're fragile" --> GitHub issue [microsoft/TypeScript#28867](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28867).  beware!

Comment: Yeah, it's a bummer. I guess until this gets figured out it will always be a problem.